# How is This Symbolic Link Not Being Followed?

Tags: symlink, libreoffice, openoffice

I have LibreOffice Writer and OpenOffice Calc installed on my OpenSuSE system.  This is arguably not ideal, but before I fully switch to one or the other, I noticed some strange behaviour when calling `oocalc file.ods` from the command line.

```
user@host:~> ooffice -calc
Warning: -calc is deprecated.  Use --calc instead.
user@host:~> oocalc
Warning: -calc is deprecated.  Use --calc instead.
user@host:~> which oocalc
/usr/bin/oocalc
user@host:~> readlink -f `which oocalc`
/opt/openoffice4/program/scalc
user@host:~> /usr/bin/oocalc
Warning: -calc is deprecated.  Use --calc instead.
user@host:~> ls -lth /usr/bin/oo*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Jan 30 17:32 /usr/bin/oocalc -> /opt/openoffice4/program/scalc
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 55 Dec 19 18:06 /usr/bin/ooffice
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 66 Dec 19 18:06 /usr/bin/oofromtemplate
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 60 Dec 19 18:06 /usr/bin/ooweb
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 63 Dec 19 18:06 /usr/bin/oowriter
user@host:~> readlink -f `which oocalc`
/opt/openoffice4/program/scalc
user@host:~> /opt/openoffice4/program/scalc
```

The last of the above commands runs OpenOffice Calc as expected.  When `oocalc` or `ooffice -calc` is executed it prints the deprecation warning and then actually opens LibreOffice *writer*, as its spreadsheet counterpart isn't installed.  My question, though, is **how is it possible for `oocalc` to resolve correctly to the symbolic link but not follow it, and execute `ooffice -calc` instead?**

**EDIT:**
The contents of `/opt/openoffice4/program/scalc` are as follows:

```
cmd=$(cd `dirname $0` && pwd)/soffice
exec "$cmd" -calc "$@"
```

Comment: What are the contents of `/opt/openoffice4/program/scalc`? My guess is that the symbolic link is being followed but the target is looking at `$0` and basing its incorrect behavior on that value.

Comment: Mark, thanks, I didn't think to look in the file but it's obvious what's happening when I do!  As you predicted, it relies on `dirname $0` to resolve the path to `ooffice`, which of course is wrong when invoked from the symbolic link in /usr/bin.  Feel free to add this as a formal answer if you want acceptance for it.

Comment: I can offer a better answer if you can post the contents of `scalc`. My version of opensuse doesn't have that file.

Comment: Do you have both `/usr/bin/soffice` and `/opt/openoffice4/program/soffice`? Do they have different contents?